# Counting words from input.txt using std::map. Need to make it case insensitive

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search-tree

I have an input.txt file which consists of words and numbers
`Helicopter 12 HELICOPTER 555 Helicopter 12 555 vehicle 555 Vehicle 13 14 15 15 YACHT`
And I have a program which converts it into two std::map, one - for words, another one - for numbers, where the key is a word(number) and value is how many times it appears in input.txt

```
    map<string, int> text, num;

    string buff;
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    if (!input)                       
    {
        cout << "No file was found\n"; 
        return 1;  
    }


    while (input >> buff) {
        if (all_of(buff.begin(), buff.end(), isdigit)) num[buff]++;
        else text[buff]++;
    }
```

The thing is I need to make it case insensitive, so 'HELICOPTER' and 'helicopter' would be considered the same kind of word and counted as 2
I tried using for_each() + tolower() for 'text', but it didn't work, the error was:
`cannot convert 'std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>' to 'int' in argument passing`
I was wondering how can I do it. And I also think it might be better if I convert input.txt tolower before making maps out of it, but I couldn't find a method to do it

Comment: `std::transform( buff.begin(), buff.end(), buff.begin(), ::tolower );`

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked. I put it after ```while (input >> buff) {``` line